# Try Catching from another Method

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Try Catch from another method:

```
method1(){
   try {

       method2();

   }catch(Exception e){


   }
}

 method2(){
    try{

       //ERROR FROM HERE

    }catch(Exception e){

    }

 }
```

How will `method1()` catch the error from `method2()`?

Comment: It won't because `method2()` already catches it. You can get rid of the `try/catch` block in `method2()` and add a `throws` declaration, though. That way the method will be carried to the caller.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`method1()` will not catch the error, unless you re-throw it from the `catch` block in `method2()`.

```
void method2() {
    try {
        // Error here
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you throw another exception in method2's catch block.

```
public void method2() {
    try {
        // ...
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    public void method1(){
        try {
            test2();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //catch test2() error
        }
    }

    public void method2() throws IOException{

    }
```

Use throws

Answer (score 0):

It won't until you re-throw it within  the `catch` block of your `method2` by adding `throw e;`.